# Entering cshell from bash

Tags: bash, csh

I have a bash script and need to run some commands in cshell inside it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo entering_to_cshell
csh
echo in_cshell
exit
echo exited_from_cshell
```

Why doesn't this script run as expected? It only prints `entering_to_cshell` and it doesn't exit from cshell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using

```
csh
```

you start a new subshell where your script isn't executed. That's why none of your following commands are executed. Your script waits for this subshell to end which, as you noted, never happens.

Try

```
csh -c "echo in_cshell"
```

This way you don't create a new subshell which isn't impacted by your script.

Answer (score 0):

By simply calling `csh` in your script, you're starting an interactive csh subshell. You'll notice that once you quit from the `csh` session, your script will then continue to with the subsequent echo and quiting on `exit`.

To pass a series of commands to `csh` from you bash script, one approach would be to use the [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) syntax to redirect commands to `csh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo entering_to_cshell

csh <<EOF
echo in_cshell
exit
EOF

echo exited_from_cshell
```

The lines between the EOF entries will be treated as a script that is interpreted by `csh`.